# Django HTML POST delete button with information

Tags: html, django, forms, post, button

I have a table with email addresses and I need to delete email addresses from the table. The table is to have delete buttons next to the email addresses.

On initial page load my view sends the email addresses to the Django template. When a user clicks the delete button next to the email address you wish to delete, I need the button to POST along the information of the corresponding email address so that my view can remove the right email address from the database.

I've looked around about submit buttons and POST information, but POST usually works by sending along input data. In this case, there is no input data. Here is the code from the template:

```
        <tr>
            <td>{% trans "Email" %}</td>
            <td>{% trans " " %}</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for licensed_user in licensed_users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ licensed_user.user.email }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form class="flex-container" method="post" action="{% url 'reseller_dashboard' %}" >
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <button name="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">DELETE
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I need to send `licensed_user.user.email` along with the POST method when the button is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a hidden input field and then handle the delete in your view. A hidden input would look something like:

```
<form class="flex-container" method="post" action="{% url 'reseller_dashboard' %}" > 
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-group"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{licensed_user.user.email}}">
    <button name="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">DELETE </button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way, you can also using ajax method;

```
{% for licensed_user in licensed_users %}
  <tr class="tr__{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ licensed_user.user.email }}</td>
    <td><button data-email="{{ licensed_user.user.email }}"
                data-loop="{{ forloop.counter }}"
                class="btn btn-default delete-action">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  $('.delete-action').click(function(){
    var email = $(this).data('email');
    var loop = $(this).data('loop');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'reseller_dashboard' %}",
      data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        'email': email,
        'delete': true
      },
      success: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
        $('.tr__' + loop).remove(); // remove this single `<tr>`
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```